# What is an execution environment?

Tags: java, multithreading, process, execution

Providing that I didn't attend college lessons on hardware or on OS topics - I've only tried to follow some youtube videos and read some online articles about it (without significant success); someone could explain me what is an *execution environment*? I study Java and now I'm starting multithreading. On an Oracle tutorial section I've found this definition of process and thread: "Both processes and threads provide an execution environment". The problem Is that I really don't get what does this mean.

Answer (score 1):

In this context, "execution environment" means a context in which code can execute (run). A *process* can use multiple *threads* in parallel. A thread executes a single stack of code at a time.

This is a gross oversimplification, but hopefully you get the point.

Comment: Where is this 'context' located? Is it a part of the OS or a particular space in the RAM? Or managed by both this components?

Answer (score 0):

'Execution Environment' or 'Environment' terms are extremely overloaded. They are used to mean different things at different context.(Somehow related though)

There many layers of abstractions in a software system. Each layer depends on something from the immediate below layers and abstracted from realities coming from layers further below. For instance, Computers depends fundamentally on physics. So at the bottom, there is physics. On top of physics, there is transistors. On top of transistors, there is logic gates. On top of logic gates, there is logic circuits. On top of that, there is microarchitecture and on top of that, there is architecture (instructions set, registers etc.). On top of that there is software written using the architecture. The software is further  divided into operating system and applications. OS and applications have layered parts themselves.

So, everything depends on something else. That something else is called environment. In other words, everything your part do not implement but depends on called 'environment'.

OS is an environment for applications because of the fact that when application performs an I/O, they use the operating system provided functionalities by making system calls.

Most platforms like JAVA or C++ runtime, further provide functionality to the applications. Hence, they are also called a form of environment.

In the context of processes and threads, these things can be said...

Operating systems do not run a single program at a time to improve hardware utilization. (When the code runs it may block for several reasons, and during that time OS runs another program). Furthermore, there is something called 'timesharing' which means OS allocates the CPU(s) to different programs for a limited amount of time and stops/continues programs.

In order to do that, OS isolates a specific instance of program execution through an abstraction called 'process'. By doing that it provides programs an 'environment' that they can use without thinking other programs running. (Isolates running programs through processes)

For instance, a program code running in a process could not read data written to the memory allocated to the another process.

Threads are like processes to some extent. They share the memory of the process they belong. Namely, they share the HEAP space of the processes but they have separate stacks. Since they have separate stacks, they could be in different parts of the same code. From stacks they have references to the shared heap which allows them to communicate more effectively than the inter process communication way.

To sum up, everything you are implicitly or explicitly benefiting but you are not implementing is called 'environment'.